# Spring Data JPA Specification FETCH JOIN Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, hql, jpql

I am trying to create below query using spring jpa specification but it is giving error.

```
SELECT x FROM Magazine x join fetch x.articles a join a.publishers p WHERE p.title = 'JDJ'
```

> Invalid path: 'generatedAlias2.title'

problem here is I am trying to do something like below

```
return (r, cq, cb) -> {

  Join join1 = (Join) root.fetch("articles");

  Join join2 = join1.join("publisher");

  return cb.equal(join2.get("title"), title);

};
```

Is it possible to create query. Please help.

Comment: Your JPQL filters by `x.title` where `x` represents `Magazine`, but `join2` refers to `Publisher`, so which is it? `Magazine.title` or `Publisher.title`?

Comment: Corrected. I wrote a sample code for my more complex problem. Typo was there. Pls help me solve the issue

Comment: Does it work if you replace `fetch` with `join`? Also, pls post the relevant entities

Comment: Yes. It works if replaced with join

Comment: Try adding a separate join to `articles`, just for the filtering, and use `cq.distinct(true)`. This should solve the issue while still keeping tolerable performance. In general, you're not supposed to filter using the fetched associations

Comment: I solved this with keeping join in specs and adding entity graph to fetch eagerly. Thanks.